# Wait for result from objective C function before continuing in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, event-handling

I have a swift app. The main class viewdidload calls an objective-c function.

The objective-c function scans a database and then puts that into a NSMutableArray.

I need to use the the NSMutable array in the swift function.

The problem is this: I call the objective-c function in swift and then use the array but it goes to use the array before it has been filled (nil).

So I need swift to wait for a successful return value from the objective-c function before sing the array.

I have seen multiple examples but not from one language to another. Some people are saying use completion handler other say that is not the best way. Then others said notification.

I am new to IOS so your help is appreciated.

EDITED ADDED CODE

**scanTable function (Objective C):**

```
#import "ScanTable.h"
#import "Mapper.h"

@implementation ScanTable

- (void) scanTableDo {
    AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];
    AWSDynamoDBScanExpression *scanExpression = [AWSDynamoDBScanExpression new];
    scanExpression.limit = @10;

    [[dynamoDBObjectMapper scan:[Mapper class] 
                     expression:scanExpression]
              continueWithBlock:
        ^id(AWSTask *task) {
            if (task.error) {
                NSLog(@"The request failed. Error: [%@]", task.error);
            }
            if (task.exception) {
                NSLog(@"The request failed. Exception: [%@]", task.exception);
            }
            if (task.result) {
                AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = task.result;
                NSMutableArray *scanResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:paginatedOutput.items];  //// ADDED /////
            }
            return nil;
    }];     
}
@end
```

**Main function (Swift):**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scanTable = ScanTable();       
    scanTable.scanTableDo();

    let swiftArray = scanTable.scanResult     
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: It's troublesome to deal with OC and Swift. And your question is too generic.

Comment: Don't listen to opinions.  Find something you can implement and get working.  As you gain more experience programming, you should gain a greater understanding of the issues involved, and why one approach is better than another.

Comment: Hi @AdamPro13 and Lumialxk Thanks for your responses. I have added the code. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @Avi as per my question I couldn't find a way that was applicable. Otherwise I would have. Thanks though.

Comment: Could you provide us with some snippet of the code so we can determine why the objc function is returning prematurely? Also, it would be great if we could see the ObjC function in question as well...

Comment: @ZeMoon not sure why it is not showing for you. I edited the question and added it.

Comment: @NicholasMuir sorry I wrote the comment before reloading the page. Blocks are indeed the right way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that this is an asynchronous function and you are trying to access the result in a synchronous way. You need the objective c function to use a block so that you can access it when it's finished:

```
- (void)scanTableDoWithBlock:(void(^)(NSArray *scanResult, NSError *error))handler {

    AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];
    AWSDynamoDBScanExpression *scanExpression = [AWSDynamoDBScanExpression new];
    scanExpression.limit = @10;


    [[dynamoDBObjectMapper scan:[Mapper class]
                     expression:scanExpression]
     continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
         if (task.error) {
             NSLog(@"The request failed. Error: [%@]", task.error);
             if (handler != nil) {
                 handler(nil, task.error);
             }
         }
         if (task.exception) {
             NSLog(@"The request failed. Exception: [%@]", task.exception);
         }
         if (task.result) {
             AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = task.result;
             NSMutableArray *scanResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:paginatedOutput.items];  //// ADDED /////

             if (handler != nil) {
                 handler([scanResult copy], nil);
             }
         } 

         return nil;
     }];    
}
```

Make sure that you change the method declaration in the .h file from:

```
- (void)scanTableDo;
```

to:

```
- (void)scanTableDoWithBlock:(void(^)(NSArray *scanResult, NSError *error))handler;
```

Comment: Thanks for that!. I got an error because no return, I added in return nil again and it fixed it (was it meant to be missing?). Also on the swift side. If I call this function and then use the array would I do this with a if statement?. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I removed the `return nil` but after looking at the `continueWithBlock:^id` that was an error, it does need a return. When you call this in swift you would use a completion handler and then yes, you can use the array as a normal array, using an if statement to check that the count is above 0 if needed. Autocomplete is swift should add the closure in for you when you write the function call.

Comment: I get the same error with the modified code "Control reaches end of non void block".

Comment: The only non-void block there is inside the `continueWithBlock`, if you returning nil there then I can't see why the compiler would be telling you that unless you have an issue elsewhere in your code. The `return nil` is the last line in the block and not inside an if statement? As shown above.

Comment: Thanks my error when pasting. Cheers for your help really appreciated.

Comment: @NicholasMuir No problem, glad I could help

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but have been having real trouble with it. it is working within the IOS block but outside of it my array is nil. If you have time would you please be able to look at attempt to pin place your solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38847930/objective-c-to-swift-dowithblock

Comment: You have to use the array inside the block. If you want to do things with it outside of the block then create a function that takes the array as a parameter and then call that function from inside the block. The block is asynchronous, so it happens after the code underneath the block